# Multi color line with shapes

Tags: android, shapes, nine-patch

i'am trying to accomplish a single line background with 3 or more colors, i want to know if its possible with xml shapes or I've to use 9 patch? i'am kind of a newbie with shapes and I've spent all morning trying to accomplish what i want but nothing.

Below is what I want to achieve:

[image]

I allready tried this shape with gradient but it only assumes the start color

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is the line -->
<item>
      <shape>
            <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#868686" />
      </shape>
</item>
<!-- This is the main color -->
<item>
     <shape>
         <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
     </shape>
</item>
```

**SOLUTION UPDATE**

Beside the answer provided by SAM, I've found the 9.png the best answer to my problem.I simple create a png with the 3 colors and then apply the nine patch and DONE :D i had used this tool weblookandfeel.com/nine-patch-editor its as simple as open the image in the app and save and you have your 9.png.

Comment: `layer-list` will put the shapes/items one on top of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using this tool for obtaining colors you want,
http://angrytools.com/gradient/

and then arrange in horizontal, one of the ideas can be, creating three drawables and arrange them using linear layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"/>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image2"/>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yap you are right it's a way but the hard one, i simple create a png with the 3 colors i want apply the nine patch to create a 9.png and voilá DONE :D nine patch it's awesome :D by the way i had used this tool http://weblookandfeel.com/nine-patch-editor/ its as simple as open the image in the app and save and you have your 9.png, but i will accept your answers because it's a valid solution thanks ;)